# Sorting Images using Active Storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I'm experimenting with Active Storage to manage images. I got the multiple uploads working, but I want to use acts_as_list position with jQuery sortable to manage their order using ajax, like in [the video on this site](https://gorails.com/episodes/sortable-drag-and-drop). In a normal model, I would run a migration to add position to the model. But it looks like I have no access to the Blob or Attachement models. How would I tackle this? Or do I have to go back to using Carrierwave? Any help would be appreciated.

FOR CLARIFICATION, let me add the code.

**show.html.erb**

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @post.title %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Content:</strong>
  <%= @post.content %>
</p>

<% if @post.images.attached? %>
<p>
  <strong>Images:</strong>
  <br>
  <div id="images" class="list-group" data-url="<%= sort_posts_path %>">
  <% @post.images.order(:position).each do |image| %>
    <%= link_to image_tag image.variant(resize: "200x200"), class: "list-group-item", id: dom_id(image) %>
  <% end %>
  </div>
</p>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@post) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', posts_path %>
```

**posts.js**

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {

  $("#images").sortable({
    update: function(e, ui) {
      /* Update active storage database entry for each POST image. */
      /* This is the RAILS AJAX from the tutorial */
      Rails.ajax({
        url: $(this).data("url"),
        type: "PATCH",
        data: $(this).sortable('serialize'),
    }
  });

});
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :posts do
    collection do
      patch :sort
    end
  end
end
```

**posts_controller.rb**

```
def sort
  params[:image].each_with_index do |id, index|
    Post.image.where(id: id).update_all(position: index + 1)
  end

  head :ok
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing to get it all to work in an actual application. It's amazing all that went into this "simple" functionality.

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'acts_as_list'
```

The **migration** for adding `position` to Active Storage.

```
class AddPositionToActiveStorageAttachments < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_column :active_storage_attachments, :position, :integer, default: 0
  end
end
```

**sorting.js**

This allows us to sort anything using the `sort-me` class.

```
$(function() {

  $(".sort-me").sortable({
    update: function(e, ui){
      ui.placeholder.height(ui.item.height());
      Rails.ajax({
        url: $(this).data("url"),
        type: "PATCH",
        data: $(this).sortable('serialize')
      });
    }
  }).disableSelection();

});
```

**edit.html.erb**

This is a snippet of the relevant code on the page. Adding the `sort-me` class to the containing div will make sortable elements out of the NEXT set of items.

```
<div id="product-attachments" class="sort-me" data-url="<%= sort_attachments_admin_products_path %>">
  <% @product.images.order(:position).each do |attachment| %>
    <div id="<%= dom_id(attachment) %>" class="ui-state-default image-box">
      <%= image_tag attachment.variant(combine_options: {auto_orient: true, thumbnail: '200x200^', gravity: 'center', extent: '200x200' }) %>
      <%= link_to "Delete", delete_image_admin_products_path(@product.id, attachment.id), method: :delete, class: "btn btn-xs", data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"} %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

**routes.rb**

These are the relevant routes. In this case were using a admin namespace. So if you using this without it, make sure your routes/paths don't include the admin part.

```
namespace 'admin' do
  resources :products do
    collection do
      patch '/products/sort/:id', action: :sort_attachments, as: 'sort_attachments'
      delete '/products/:id/images/:image_id', action: 'delete_image', as: 'delete_image'
    end
  end
end
```

**products_controller.rb**

Corresponding controller actions for **sort** and **delete** routes.

```
def sort_attachments
  params[:attachment].each_with_index do |id, index|
    ActiveStorage::Attachment.where(id: id).update_all(position: index + 1)
  end

  head :ok
end

def delete_image
  ActiveStorage::Attachment.where(id: params[:image_id])[0].purge
  redirect_to edit_admin_product_path(params[:id]), notice: 'Image was successfully deleted.'
end
```

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE A much better way**
Given that MyModel.images returns an array of ActiveStorageAttachment models I have just done a test by creating a migration to add a position column to the `active_storage_attachments` table
Then using this field to order the images works perfectly

```
rails g migration add_order_by_to_active_storage_attachments position:integer
```

Obviously don't forget to run the migration and you might want to edit the migration to update the position field on existing records before you run it.

Now you can set the position field to whatever values you want and then you can just use
`my_model.images.order(:position)`

If it would be helpful to you for me to expand on this answer then just ask in the comments

UPDATE for further clarity, it is the array of images that need to be sorted right? To enable this to happen, the position field you've just created in the migration needs to be set when the form is posted back to the controller after the images have been re-organised in the view.

So, in the relevant controller actions, update and create, you can loop through the the `@post.images` setting the position for each image and save the image back to the database. That will make sure that when you view the images with the `@post.images.order(:position)` you will get them displayed in the correct order.

Comment: So, to test this I'm using a Post model. I got the images to sort but when following the video, and adding the SORT action in the controller, the example shows how to sort the posts, not the images of the post, so they don't persist. It shows Post.where(id: id).update_all(position: index + 1) but this would sort the POST itself, not the images. Should it be something like Post.image?

Comment: So you add the position column to the active_storage_attachments table.Then in your view or wherever it is that you need to display the images you do @post.images.order(:position). You need to save the position of each image when you sort them by doing `image.position = 1` etc...

Comment: @Tony I've updated my answer but I'm not sure what level of knowledge you have so I'm unsure if what I have said will be enough to get you on your way so please feel free to ask for more help

Comment: I added the code for clarification. In the tutorial, the POSTS are the things being sorted by position. In this example, the post's active storage IMAGES need to be sorted. I can drag in the UI just fine but when I refresh the page, it goes right back to original position. I looked in the console and hte position does not update. The JS, that does the updating, is not working. I hope this clarifies what's going on.

Comment: @TonyS. So the position is not getting updated. Eitherr the sort function is not being called or the paraqms are not correct.

Comment: @TonyS. Thank you. so the position is not being saved to the database. Did you check the actual data in the table? Probably the sort method is not being called or the params hash is wrong. So some debugging is needed as your code looks OK. Can you post the log entries for the point at which the sort method in the controller is called? Also check in your browser for any errors by using the inspect element option in Firefox or Chrome and looking at the console tab which should show any javascript errors

Comment: @TonyS. I have created a chat room https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184866/rails-chat to discuss this further in a more appropriate manner. Feel free to join if you think it will help

Comment: Please check out my answer below. I couldn't get in your chat because my reputation level was not high yet. Thanks for all the help.